# Extract Numbers from a Mathematical Expression String

Tags: java, string

I want to extract Numbers from a simple mathematical expression String;
I first replace all mathematical characters in the String with spaces and then try to split String with spaces then I put numbers to an ArrayList

```
public ArrayList<Integer> retriveNumbers(String Expr) {
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList();
    Expr = Expr.replaceAll("^", " ");
    Expr = Expr.replaceAll("[*]", " ");
    Expr = Expr.replaceAll("/", " ");
    Expr = Expr.replaceAll("[+]", " ");
    Expr = Expr.replaceAll("-", " ");
    Expr = Expr.replaceAll("%", " ");
    String[] elements = Expr.split(" ");
    for(String e : elements){
        numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(e));
    }
    return  numbers;
}
```

but when I test it I give error in output on `numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(e));`

```
Calculator c1 = new Calculator();
ArrayList<Integer> arr = c1.retriveNumbers("4*5-2+1");
for(int i: arr)
    System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: Did you check the list returned by retrieveNumbers() method, what are its contents?

Comment: Try printing `e` on console before parsing

Comment: You are working with java 6 or 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

No need to replace Each and every special character.

you can simple replace non number with empty
i.e

```
str=str.replaceAll("[^0-9]","");
```

**Example:**

```
 String str="asdfas234234**&^%*&";

      str=str.replaceAll("[^0-9]","");

  System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: Check here http://browxy.com/SubmittedCode/12722

Comment: If I want to keep negative sign and floating point, what do I must do?

Comment: @Ehsan str=str.replaceAll("[^-0-9.]","");use this

Comment: @Ehsan http://browxy.com/SubmittedCode/12722

Answer (score 3):

You need to assigned the replaced strings back to Expr-

```
Expr = Expr.replaceAll("^", " "); // do this for all replacements
```

And, also check for empty string-

```
        if(!e.isEmpty()) {
            numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(e));
        }
```

That's it, it will work with these changes.

Answer (score 2):

*Strings* are *immutable*, the operations you perform on them make new results, so you need to assign it to *new String*:

```
Expr = Expr.replaceAll("^", " ");
```

And the same for all the others.

BTW, I recommend you to follow [Java naming conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm) and change the String name to `expr` (begin with a small letter) and the method name to `RetriveNumbers` with capital R.

Answer (score 1):

Use like this

```
class test
{
public static ArrayList<Integer> retriveNumbers(String Expr){
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList();
String[] elements = Expr.replaceAll("[^0-9]"," ").replaceAll("\\s+"," ").trim().split(" ");;
for(String e : elements){
    numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(e));
}
return  numbers;
}
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
ArrayList<Integer> arr =retriveNumbers("4*5-2+1");
for(int i: arr)
    System.out.println(i);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the 
[Pattern javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

```
String expression = "4.43*5-2+1";
String expNumbers = expression.replaceAll("[^0-9\\.]", " ");
System.out.println(expNumbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below one liner solution.

```
  expr = expr.replaceAll("[\\^*%\\-+\\\\]", " ");
```

Complete class will look like below code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculator c1 = new Calculator();
        List<Integer> arr = c1.retriveNumbers("4*5-2+1");
        for(int i: arr)
            System.out.println(i);
    }

    public List<Integer> retriveNumbers(String expr) {
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        expr = expr.replaceAll("[\\^*%\\-+\\\\]", " ");
        String[] elements = expr.split(" ");
        for (String e : elements) {
            numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(e));
        }
        return numbers;
    }

}
```